# javascript random color with 7digits must

Tags: javascript, colors, random

I found the following awesome script to create a random color with javascript.

```
var randColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

only problem I have with this script is that it's not garanteed that it returns a normal 7digit hex string.

sometimes it's just 6 digits long like #e1d19.

is there a way to kind of force a 7 digit hex value?

thank you for your help.

edit: this is my actual problem:

```
function randColor() {
    var randColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    return randColor;
}

for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    $("#colorpicker").append("<div class='color' title="+randColor()+" style='background:"+randColor()+"'></div>");
}
```

I'm creating little divs with a random color, when I click on them I grab their title attribute and I'm coloring the background of my body.

however currently my code ends in

```
<div style="background:rgb(176, 249, 252);" title="#8bc47d" class="color"></div>
```

so when I grab the title attribute the color I'm giving my body is a different one than the little div shows.

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you want is a **6** digit hex value preceded by a "#" character, for a total of 7 characters.

Comment: You're getting different colors because you're calling randColor twice, giving you two different colors. You'll want to call it once, store it in a variable and use the variable twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just pad it yourself:

```
function randomColor() {
  var rc = (~~(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF)).toString(16);
  return '#' + new Array(7 - rc.length).join('0') + rc;
}
```

This trick:

```
new Array(n).join(char)
```

is a way to get `n - 1` copies of "char" in a string. I subtracted the raw length of the value from 7 instead of 6 so that when the string is 5 characters long I get one zero, when 4 I get two, etc.

*edit* — of course (as mentioned in other answers) you can get pad zeros like this too:

```
  return '#' + "000000".slice(rc.length) + rc;
```

I'd have to do one of those silly jsperf things to see which is faster :-)

Comment: or `return '#' + ("000000" + rc).slice(-6);`

Comment: yes that works too - thought the negative argument to "slice" raises memories of some browser not implementing that; maybe a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
var randColor = '#'+(0xFFFFFFFF-Math.random()*0xFFFFFFFF).toString(16).substr(0, 6);
```

Comment: Easily the best answer so far, least convoluted and reads very well; kudos!

Comment: ... except, what about when `Math.random()` returns 0.99?  The result of the subtraction problem will be a number close to zero, so we'll be faced with the exact same problem.

Comment: Pointy you are right. But in this case browser render white color. It's trick :)

Comment: One more thing. Math random returns a number with 16 digits after decimal point. What probability returning 0.9900000000000000? And it's not a trick :)

Comment: @Lex ??  When `Math.random()` returns a number close to 1, then that expression in parenthesis will be a small integer, right?  When you convert that small integer to a string, it will have fewer than 6 digits. How will that result in a valid color string?

Comment: @Pointy. It's not true. There is a Number object in parenthesis. If Number objects don’t have a decimal point or fractional component, they’re treated as integers.

Comment: @Lex, OK, let's do this.  `(0xFFFFFF - (0.9912) * 0xFFFFFF << 0)` is (decimal) 147639.  Convert that to hex (with `.toString(16)`) and you get "240b7", and that's only 5 characters long.

Comment: @Lex any random value larger than about 0.9375 will produce a too-short result.

Comment: @Pointy. Look, I really understand what you said. It's absolutely true in pure theory. But some things failed in theory and work in practice because of probability theory points. As well as Math.random returns PSEUDOrandom, but it's enough in practice.
For example, what probability of getting not only value larger then 0.9375 for 100 cases? It's so insignificant. We may ignore it with no worry.

Comment: Anyway you have already proposed a solution which user239831 took.
That's all.

Comment: @Lex the probability that your method will fail is about 6/100, or 6%.  In 100 cases, you'd probably have 6 that fail.

Comment: OK :) It's easy to solve that problem. But solution is not enough. Let's optimize: rc = '#' + (0xFFFFFFFF-Math.random()*0xFFFFFFFF).toString(16).substr(0, 6);

Answer (score 1):

Here's my (low tech) attempt:

```
var randColor = (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
while( randColor.length < 6 ) {
    randColor = '0' + randColor;
}
randColor = '#' + randColor;
```

Comment: Also, you're only padding the R value that way. What if the G value is the single-digit culprit?

Comment: @Gabi: what makes you think so? He is just prepending with zeros like you do in your answer.

Comment: I am just padding randColor with 0's in the front.  It looks like what you are trying to do as well.

Comment: @jdv sorry about that, I wasn't paying very much attention. You are right

Comment: @Dutchie432: The only way digits are missing is if there are leading zeroes in the number (i.e. 012345 == 12345). With a five character string, red will always be the culprit provided the channels are ordered RGB.

Comment: Okay...I wasn't sure on that, so I decided to go the safe route on my post. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to make 3 sets of 2-digit hex numbers (one for each R, G, and B). Then, simply pad-left each with a 0 to ensure they are all two digits. Maybe something like this untested code I am providing for reference :)

```
//I am GUESSING that this is how you get a 2-digit hex value ranging 0-255
var r = PadDigits(Math.random()*0xFF<<0).toString(16),2);
var g = PadDigits(Math.random()*0xFF<<0).toString(16),2);
var b = PadDigits(Math.random()*0xFF<<0).toString(16),2);

var randColor = '#'+r+g+b;

function PadDigits(n, totalDigits) 
{ 
    n = n.toString(); 
    var pd = ''; 
    if (totalDigits > n.length) 
    { 
        for (i=0; i < (totalDigits-n.length); i++) 
        { 
            pd += '0'; 
        } 
    } 
    return pd + n.toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be six digits, not seven, but the resulting string should be seven characters long including the hash. Nitpicking, I know, but still. How about this:

```
var color = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
"#" + String(color + "000000").slice(0, 6);
```

If you want to pad in the beginning instead, this should do it:

```
var color = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
"#" + String("000000" + color).slice(-6);
```

To clarify, this will pad the *whole* string, not separate channels. I'm thinking that since you're not randomizing per channel, there's really only the red or blue channel you're looking to pad (probably red, i.e., the second snippet).

Your second problem is that you're calling randColor twice, giving you two different colors. You'll want to store the generated color in a variable and use the variable twice instead.

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    var color = randColor();
    $("#colorpicker").append("<div class='color' title=" + color + " style='background:" + color + "'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody posted it and this is the shortest code i got to get a random color.

```
'#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6)
```

- It will get a random float number 0.437920...
- Convert it to Hexadecimal, you'll get something like that 0.7c13b41830e33
- Take the 6 last character which will provide you a random color #

Easy to understand, short and efficient.